# Comparison operators in SQLite are performed on all rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose that we have a table called `agents` and an integer column called `commission` with 100000 rows, and then we will do the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM agents
WHERE commission > 5;
```

Will the database iterate through all the rows in the table? this can be very slow if we have many rows.
I am working with SQLite

Comment: You can add an index on the `commission` column.

Comment: _this can be very slow if we have many rows_ - that's one of the major challenges when working with somewhat bigger tables.

Comment: @jarlh No, not really - that's what indexes are for. Searching tabular data _never needs to be slow_, regardless of the size of the table, provided there are indexes defined that match the queries being run. In the OP's case, they should run `CREATE INDEX IX_commission ON agents ( commission ) INCLUDE ( etc )`. And they should avoid `SELECT *` so the `INCLUDE` list can be defined.